# onCreateView is called after returning back from second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragment-lifecycle, onrestoreinstancestate

I have MainActivityFragment from where I start DetailActivity with below code:

```
private final CurrencyListAdapter.ClickListener itemClickListener
        = new CurrencyListAdapter.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
        String code = mCurrencyList.get(position).getCode();
        intent.putExtra(Constants.SELECTED_CODE_KEY, code);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

After that from my DetailActivity I start my DetailActivityFragment with below code:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        DetailActivityFragment fragment = DetailActivityFragment.getInstance(code);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Also I am retaining the instance state within my MainActivityFragment.  However, while hitting back button from DetailActivityFragment, onCreateView method of my MainActivityFragment is called and I am not able to restore instance state, because saveInstanceState method is not executed and thus the savedInstanceState is null.
I am very curious why this happening. This is not happening in other project wich has the same logic. I will be very thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: is there anybody who wants to help?

Comment: I know because every time when I return back, app loads data from web API instead of using already fetched data stored in bundle. Also I can see this behaviour during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured it out. I was loading MainActivity through xml layout file. I changed this and included the following code into my MainActivity and after the issue is gone:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    MainActivityFragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.main_container, fragment)
        .commit();
}
```